# Is there any fixed assignment for int and char if not assigned?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(void)
{   char m,n;
    printf("%d\n",m);//value of m
    printf("%d",n);//value of n
}
```

in the above snippet value of m is always printed as 0 why?why it doesn't change even after multiple times compilation is it automatically assigned if we do not assign while the value of n always changes so why not both change randomly every time i compile?

---

Am i missing any concept?

Comment: They don't have any value; they are uninitialized and their values are *indeterminate*.

Comment: It is possible that the compiler generates code that sets local variables to 0, but it is not required to do so, and does not contravene the C standard. It is also possible that the value always *happens* to be 0 for some reason not worth exploring. Either way, you must set the value specifically before reading it.

Answer (score 0):

Local variables like yours are automatic variables. They are allocated on stack memory and their value is garbage.

Global variables are implicitly have static storage class and have value `0` by default.

Since `m` is a local variable, its value needn't always be the same. It is indeterminate. This memory location can be given to other processes.